# How to perform calculations on rows based on selected data frame columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, median

I have a data frame with mixed character and numeric values in different columns. I want to perform a calculation (similar to `summary()`) on values in rows but using only a selection of columns and put them into new columns. I have a vector of column names to use in `columns <- colnames(df)[from_column:to_column]`.
Calculating columns with values in a given row is easy since there is `rowSums()`

`df$n <- rowSums(!is.na(df[ , columns]))`

similarly for mean with `rowMeans()`

`df$mean <- rowMeans(df[ , columns], na.rm = TRUE)` (I have NAs)

however, I want to get `min()`, `median()`, and `max()` as well, with

```
df$min <- min(df[ , columns], na.rm = TRUE)
df$median <- median(df[ , columns], na.rm = TRUE)
df$min <- max(df[ , columns], na.rm = TRUE)
```

but the `min()` and `max()` put the same value for all rows, and `median()` returns `Error in median.default(df[, columns], na.rm = TRUE) :  need numeric data` which is even more intriguing for me as it is the same subset `df[ , columns]` and other functions compute the values but for `median()` they aren't numeric?!

Can anyone help me with the calculations and give a hint of what is wrong with `median()`?

Best regards, Marcin

Comment: try, e.g., `apply(X = df, MARGIN = 2L , FUN = max)`, use `na.rm`argument if necessary.

Comment: for min and max, you can use `do.call(df, pmin)`, and `do.call(df, pmax)`. For median, `apply(df, 1, median, na.rm=T)`. Check also the `matrixStats` package, which has functions `rowMins`, `rowMaxs` and `rowMedians`

Comment: Thanks! `apply(X = df, MARGIN = 1L , FUN = median, na.rm = TRUE)` does it